# How can I change the color of a Putty session based on the directory I'm browsing?

Tags: putty, colors, console

I'm not interested in a definitive change of colors for Putty (or terminal), but in a color specific change based on the directory I'm currently browsing, especially to avoid big mistakes between two similars directories I have read/write rights on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your bash prompt based on the path.

See:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html
- http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php#cmd_prompt

Or just google for "configure prompt bash"